# K8s Service as DaemonSet

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a possibility to have a service in all namespaces of k8s dynamically deployed?

Right now, glusterFS endpoint(ns dependent) is being deleted by k8s if the port is not in use anymore.
Ex:

```
{
  "kind": "Endpoints",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "glusterfs"
  },
  "subsets": [
    {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "ip": "172.0.0.1"
        }
      ],
      "ports": [
        {
          "port": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I made a svc for port 1 to be used all the time, so I dont end up with a missing/deleted endpoint in any ns.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: glusterfs
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1
```

It would be interesting to have the above service deployed dynamically every time someone creates a new namespace.

Comment: k8s Service is just abstract thing, which is behind the scene are IPtable rules manage by kube-proxy( its on all of the node already)

Comment: You could write a controller that created services in every namespace, I suppose, but the use case for this isn't totally clear.  (Remember that you can use hostnames like `glusterfs.otherns.svc.cluster.local` to call a service living in some other namespace; port 1, reserved for the RFC 1078 multiplexing protocol, also seems like an odd choice.)

Comment: Why endpoint is deleted?is this a expected feature?

Answer (score 1):

DaemonSet is used to deploy Exactly one replica per node.

coming to your question, why do you need to create same service across namespaces? 
It is not supported out of box though. However, you can create a custom script to achieve it.

Comment: as I said above, I need that service available in all namespaces, because the glusterFS endpoint is using port 1, and if its not used the endpoints are deleted.

Comment: you need to develop a custom script to scan through the namespaces and if the service is not found then create it

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of that, but I had some hopes.

Answer (score 0):

K8s doesn't have any replication of services, pods, deployments, secrets, etc across namespaces... out of the box.

Introducing...The Kubernetes Controller/Operator Pattern.

Deploy a controller pod that has a read/list permissions on the namespaces resource.  This controller will "watch" the namespaces and deploy whatever resources you want when they show up or change.

To get started building your own operator or controller please look at kubebuilder. https://book.kubebuilder.io/